# Predicting an annual event – modeling on an annual or monthly basis?

Tags: modeling, experiment-design, data-preprocessing

Suppose I'm interested in predicting which of my current customers are likely to renew their insurance *at some point* in the year. The renewal can happen at any time in the year. I want to proactively reach out to those customers **not likely** to renew in the year. Some customers are great, renewing annually in the same month as they did previously. These people I probably wouldn't want to reach out to until the end of the year (if they hadn't already renewed, of course), since they're probably low-hanging fruit who, for whatever reason, haven't yet renewed. Other customers are a bit more sporadic – some don't renew after one year and I never see them again, while others renew but may take a few months after their policy has expired.

I'm trying to determine the best way of setting my dataset up, from an experimental design standpoint. I see two primary options:

1. model each customer at an annual level
2. model each customer at a monthly level

The dataset for 1 could look something like this:

```
customer_id renewed_at_all_in_year renewed_month_this_year renewed_month_last_year  number_of_interactions_in_year
a                 1                                      2                       2                               5
b                 0                                   null                       1                               2
c                 0                                   null                       2                               0
d                 1                                      1                       2                               9
```

where the dependent variable is `renewed_at_all_in_year`. The dataset for 2 could look something like this:

```
customer_id  current_month  renewed_at_all_in_year  renewed_in_month renewed_month_last_year  policy_still_valid  needs_renewal  months_since_policy_expiration
a                        3                       1                 0                       2                   0              1                               1
a                        4                       1                 1                       2                   0              1                               2
b                        2                       0                 0                       1                   0              1                               1
b                        3                       0                 0                       1                   0              1                               2
b                        4                       0                 0                       1                   0              1                               3
c                        3                       0                 0                       2                   0              1                               1
c                        4                       0                 0                       2                   0              1                               2
d                        3                       1                 1                       2                   0              1                               1
```

where the dependent variable is `renewed_in_month`, and records for each customer are included up until they renew (i.e. once a customer renews, we won't include any more customer-months of theirs, and if a customer never renews, we include all months up until the end of the year after they are up for renewal).

The process for scoring each customer runs on a monthly basis. In both cases above, various features will have a temporal component, e.g. `number_of_interactions_in_year` for the annual-level model, or `months_since_policy_expiration` for the monthly-level model.

I see arguments for both approaches, and in the past the first approach has been successful.

I'm wondering, however, if the second approach is the more appropriate way of modeling this behavior. If a list of customers is procured/acted upon each month containing those not very likely to renew, it makes a lot of sense that a feature like `months_since_policy_expiration` would be very important there (the reason being the further you are from your renewal due date, the less likely you are to renew). I'm not sure this temporal phenomenon is appropriately captured in the annual approach. I mean, I guess various "profiles" of individuals do exist in the annual approach, but there's no explicit link between the month in which we're scoring records and any features in the annual-approach dataset. You'd simply have a model (with other features, likely) that had `renewed_month_last_year` as a feature, but no indication of how that interacts with the scoring month, because the training data for the non-renewing customers on an annual basis would be through December. At the moment, someone who renewed in February of the previous year, holding all else constant, would have the same predicted renewal likelihood in each month, which seems unintuitive.

Additionally, say I had a feature like `number_of_months_since_first_policy`. In the annual modeling approach, seeing as each "temporal" feature would have data through the end of the year since there was no policy renewal event off of which to anchor, wouldn't it be problematic that, on average, non-renewing customers would have higher values for `number_of_months_since_first_policy` vs. those renewing? This doesn't make intuitive sense – you would think that the longer a customer is with us, the more likely they are to continue renewing.

Any ideas on which approach might be more appropriate in this case? What is more appropriate from an experimental design PoV?

Comment: As everything is measured monthy, it seems to makes more sense to have a monthly outcome. But it is also a substantive question: it depends on what is more important to your company. However, you seem to be describing a time-to-event survival analysis. But you mentioned "an experimental design". As far as I know, an experimental design assumes that you have (at least) two very similar groups (almost identical on average), and an intervention that is applied to just one group (treatment) but not to the other (control). I could not get those elements from your question..